# cisco: get mac address from cdp neighbors

Tags: cisco, switch, mac, snmp

I need to find out the MAC addresses and ports of devices connected directly to a Cisco switch, preferably via SNMP. the best way i found is with CDP neighbors, but i don't find the MAC addresses, only ip and hostname.

currently i get the mac from the ip via *RFC1286-MIB::dot1dTpFdbPort*, but this is very unreliable as ip addresses are not always listed in this table. does someone know a better way to retrieve the mac address?

Answer (score 6):

cdp neighbors will show you other Cisco devices and on what port they are attached. If you're looking for the mac on those devices, do a show mac address-table dynamic interface X where X is the interface on which the device is connected. You can leave off interface X to see all mac addresses of devices connected to the switch. Not sure how to get this via SNMP

Comment: Well, yes, but the MAC table for that port will have all the devices connected to the connected switch, too..

Comment: @Shane. True, if the connected device is a switch. If it's a router - you're all set. In the case of a switch, I suppose I would get the IP from show cdp neigh details, ping it from the switch, then show arp | inc IP to get the MAC of the switch.

Answer (score 1):

SolarWinds [Switch Port Mapper](http://www.solarwinds.com/products/toolsets/switch-port-mapper.aspx), available as part of the Network Engineer's Toolset is a great tool that will do what you are asking as long as the switch's management interface [supports the proper SNMP OIDs](http://knowledgebase.solarwinds.com/kb/questions/2586/What+object+identifiers+%28OIDs%29+does+Switch+Port+Mapper+require?).  Both a GUI and CLI (Windows command window) available.

A lot of good details in the [Switch Port Mapper Documentation](http://www.solarwinds.com/documentation/switchportmapper/docs/SwitchPortMapperDocumentation/SwitchPortMapper.htm) as well.

A trial is available, the full version comes with Engineer's Toolset or can be purchased separately.

I do not work for SolarWinds but can speak very highly of Engineer's Toolset.